# javascript if (.href="myimage.png") { tekstEL.innerHTML = "This is a red car that costs " + price;}

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, button, href

I can't manage to make an if function that prints according to what picture is being shown. I have two buttons that can change a picture, but I want the function to print something unique to the picture showing. Basically, when I change the color on the vehicle in the "Exteriør" area, I want it to change the images being used for the next step "felger". Its a car design website, so when you change the car color it has to change the images being used when changing the rims in the next step.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="no">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kaldstart</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nettside.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" 
href="bilder/dekk.png">
</head>
  <body class="designpage">
      <!-- menu -->   
    <header id="header">
      <nav id="top-navbar">
        <div id="home">
          <a onclick="history.back()"><img src="bilder/logo.png" 
alt="logo Kaldstart"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="top-menu">
          <li class="menu-item meny">
            <a 
onclick="window.scroll(document.body.scrollHeight,0)">
Eksteriør</a>
            <div class="meny-innhold">
                <a onclick="window.scroll(0,450)">Felger</a>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a onclick="window.scroll(0,956)">Interiør</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a onclick="window.scroll(0,1495)">Utstyr</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a onclick="window.scroll(0,1990)">Din Porsche 911 
Carrera 4 GTS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a 
onclick="window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight)">Se mer</a>
          </li>
        </ul>  
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
      <br>
      <br>
      <!-- color change -->
    <h1 class="textdesign3">Exteriør</h1>
    <div class="containerdesign">
        <div class="imagedesign">
          <img id ="car" src="Bilder/GTSwhite.png" alt="Porsche 
911 Carrera 4 GTS skrå vinkel">
        </div>
        <div class="textdesign">
          <h2>Exteriørfarge</h2>
          <div class="horizontal-flex-container block1"> 
            <div class="hoverable">
              <div><button onclick="GTSwhite()" id="whiteext" 
class="buttonglow coloredbutton white"></button></div>
              <span class="hoverable__tooltip1">Carrera White 
Metallic - 15.100 kr</span>
            </div>
            <div class="hoverable">
              <div><button onclick="GTSgray()" id="greyext" 
class="buttonglow coloredbutton grey"></button></div> 
              <span class="hoverable__tooltip2">Aventurine Green 
Metallic - 15.100 kr</span>
            </div>
            <div class="hoverable">
              <div><button onclick="GTSred()" id="redext" 
class="buttonglow coloredbutton red"></button></div> 
              <span class="hoverable__tooltip3">Carmine Red - 
 33.000 kr</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>   
      <!-- rim change -->
    <div class="containerdesign">
      <div class="textdesign2">
        <h2>Felger</h2>
        <div class="horizontal-flex-container block1">
          <div class="hoverable">
            <div><button onclick="GTSgloss()" id="glossrims" 
class="buttonfade round"><img src="Bilder/whiteRim.png" 
alt="hvite felger"></button></div>
            <span class="hoverable__tooltip4">20/21" Carrera S- 
felger - 0 kr</span>
          </div>
          <div class="hoverable">
            <div><button onclick="GTSsilk()" id="silkrims" 
class="buttonfade round"><img src="Bilder/blackRim.png" 
alt="svarte felger"></button></div>
            <span class="hoverable__tooltip5">20/21" Turbo S- 
felger 'Svart Silkeglans' - 0 kr</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="imagedesign">
        <img id ="car2" src="Bilder/whiteGloss.png" alt="Porsche 
911 Carrera 4 GTS sidevinkel">
      </div>
    </div>  
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr class="strek1">
      <!-- interior change -->
      <h1 class="textdesign3">Interiør</h1>
      <div class="containerdesign">
        <div class="imagedesign">
          <img id ="seat" src="Bilder/beigeSeat.png" alt="Porsche 
911 Carrera 4 GTS interiør">
        </div>
        <div class="textdesign">
          <h2>Interiørfarge</h2>
          <div class="horizontal-flex-container block1"> 
            <div class="hoverable">
              <div><button onclick="GTSbeige()" id="beigeint" 
class="buttonglow coloredbutton beige"></button></div>
              <span class="hoverable__tooltip6">Skinninteriør 
'Black/Mojave Beige' - 55.600 kr</span>
            </div>
            <div class="hoverable">
              <div><button onclick="GTSblack()" id="blackint" 
class="buttonglow coloredbutton black"></button></div> 
              <span class="hoverable__tooltip7">Skinninteriør 
'Slate Grey' - 48.400 kr</span>
            </div>
            <div class="hoverable">
              <div><button onclick="GTSbrown()" id="browning" 
class="buttonglow coloredbutton brown"></button></div>
              <span class="hoverable__tooltip8">Club 
skinninteriør 'Truffle Brown' - 65.700 kr</span> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr class="strek1">
        <!-- equipment change -->
    <h1 class="textdesign3">Utstyr</h1>
    <div class="containerdesign">
        <div class="textdesign2">
          <h2>Soltak</h2>
          <div class="horizontal-flex-container block1"> 
            <div class="hoverable">
              <div><button onclick="GTSsun()" id="glassroof" 
class="buttonfade round"><img src="Bilder/sunRoof.png" 
alt="soltak på"></button></div>
              <span class="hoverable__tooltip9">Elektrisk soltak- 
glass - 27.400 kr</span>
            </div>
            <div class="hoverable">
              <div><button onclick="GTSroof()" id="nrmroof" 
class="buttonfade round down"><img src="Bilder/roof.png" 
alt="soltak av"></button></div> 
              <span class="hoverable__tooltip10">Normalt tak - 0 
kr</span> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imagedesign">
          <img id ="carRoof" src="Bilder/whiteRoof.png" 
alt="Porsche 911 Carrera 4 GTS">
        </div>
      </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr class="strek1">
        <br>
      <!-- your Porsche -->
      <div class="button centblk" id="button1">
        <div id="underline"></div>
        <a onclick="seBilen">kalkuler pris</a> 
      </div>
    <div id="dinbil">
    <h1 class="textdesign3">Din Porsche 911 Carrera 4 GTS</h1>
        <div class="textdesign4" id="price"><h3></h3></div>
        <div class="box4" id="carrerareslt"><img 
src="Bilder/blackNGreySun.png" alt="Porsche 911 Carrera 4 GTS" 
width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr class="strek1">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="horizontal-flex-container">
          <a id="fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/porsche"><img 
src="Bilder/facebook.png"></a>
          <a id="ig" href="https://www.instagram.com/porsche/">. 
<img src="Bilder/instagram.png" class="space"></a>
          <a id="yt" href="https://www.youtube.com/c/Porsche">. 
<img src="Bilder/youtube.png" class="space"></a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    /* sticky header */
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    var navbar = document.getElementById("header");
    
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
    
    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
    /* image changers */
    function GTSwhite(){ 
        document.getElementById('car') 
        .src="Bilder/GTSwhite.png"; 
        document.getElementById('car2') 
        .src="Bilder/whiteGloss.png"; 
        document.getElementById('carRoof') 
        .src="Bilder/whiteRoof.png"; 
    } 

    function GTSgray(){ 
        document.getElementById('car') 
        .src="Bilder/GTSgrey.png";
        document.getElementById('car2') 
        .src="Bilder/greyGloss.png"; 
        document.getElementById('carRoof') 
        .src="Bilder/greyRoof.png";
    } 

    function GTSred(){ 
        document.getElementById('car') 
        .src="Bilder/GTSred.png";
        document.getElementById('car2') 
        .src="Bilder/redGloss.png"; 
        document.getElementById('carRoof') 
        .src="Bilder/redRoof.png"; 
    } 

    function GTSbeige(){ 
        document.getElementById('seat') 
        .src="Bilder/beigeSeat.png"; 
    } 

    function GTSblack(){ 
        document.getElementById('seat') 
        .src="Bilder/blackSeat.png"; 
    } 

    function GTSbrown(){ 
        document.getElementById('seat') 
        .src="Bilder/brownSeat.png"; 
    } 

    function GTSgloss(){ 
        document.getElementById('car2') 
        .src="Bilder/whiteGloss.png"; 
    }

    var image_tracker = 'w';
    function GTSglosss(){ 
        var image = document.getElementById('car3') 
        if(image_tracker == 'w'){
        image.src="Bilder/whiteGloss.png"; 
        image_tracker = 'b'; 
        } else{ image.src="Bilder/whiteBlack.png";
        image_tracker = 'w'; }
    }

    function GTSsilk(){ 
        document.getElementById('car2') 
        .src="Bilder/whiteBlack.png"; 
    }

    function GTSsun(){ 
        document.getElementById('carRoof') 
        .src="Bilder/whiteSunRoof.png"; 
    }

    function GTSroof(){ 
        document.getElementById('carRoof') 
        .src="Bilder/whiteRoof.png"; 
    }

    let whiteextEl = document.querySelector("#whiteext");
    let greyextEl = document.querySelector("#greyext");
    let redextEl = document.querySelector("#greyext");
    let glossrimsEl = document.querySelector("#glossrims");
    let silkrimsEl = document.querySelector("#silkrims");
    let beigeintEl = document.querySelector("#beigeint");
    let blackintEl = document.querySelector("#blackint");
    let brownintEl = document.querySelector("#brownint");
    let glassroofEl = document.querySelector("#glassroof");
    let nrmroofEl = document.querySelector("#nrmroof");
    let dinbilEl = document.querySelector("#dinbil");
    let button1El = document.querySelector("#button1");
    let carreraresltEl = document.querySelector("#carrerareslt");
    let priceEl = document.querySelector("#price");

    /* last car example */
    button1El.addEventListener("click", seBilen);

    function seBilen()  {
    let wprice = 15100;
    let gprice = 15100;
    let rprice = 33000;
    let grim = 0;
    let brim = 0;
    let beint = 55600;
    let blint = 48400;
    let brint = 65700;
    let sroof = 27400;
    let roof = 0;

    let wwbes = wprice + grim + beint + sroof + 2061900;
    let wwber = wprice + grim + beint + roof + 2061900;
    let wwbls = wprice + grim + blint + sroof + 2061900;
    let wwblr = wprice + grim + blint + roof + 2061900;
    let wwbrs = wprice + grim + brint + sroof + 2061900;
    let wwbrr = wprice + grim + brint + roof + 2061900;

    let gwbes = gprice + grim + beint + sroof + 2061900;
    let gwber = gprice + grim + beint + roof + 2061900;
    let gwbls = gprice + grim + blint + sroof + 2061900;
    let gwblr = gprice + grim + blint + roof + 2061900;
    let gwbrs = gprice + grim + brint + sroof + 2061900;
    let gwbrr = gprice + grim + brint + roof + 2061900;

    let rwbes = rprice + grim + beint + sroof + 2061900;
    let rwber = rprice + grim + beint + roof + 2061900;
    let rwbls = rprice + grim + blint + sroof + 2061900;
    let rwblr = rprice + grim + blint + roof + 2061900;
    let rwbrs = rprice + grim + brint + sroof + 2061900;
    let rwbrr = rprice + grim + brint + roof + 2061900;

    if (document.getElementById('whiteext').clicked == true) { 
    priceEl.innerHTML = "Din total = " + wwbes + " Kr"; }
    else {
        priceEl.innerHTML = "Din total = " + gwbes + " Kr"; }   
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you getting hung up? There are no elements with ids `car`, `car2`, or `carRoof` in your html here.

Comment: these are just snippets of the code, maby I should add the whole thing for better understanding. No hang up, just no clue how to do the code, difficult to explain it...

Comment: Unfortunately, SO isn't a coding service. Read up on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your code, specifying where you're having trouble. You say you "can't manage to" so it sounds like you've made an attempt, which you should post here.